# How would I change the colour of an object using 'OnMouseEnter'?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

The script used to be:

```
function OnMouseEnter()
{
    renderer.material.color = Color.grey;
}
```

But using that is now obsolete after an update and I have no idea what the current syntax is or how one would go about finding it out. I've searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Probably because the field `renderer` is outdated. Nowadays you get the renderer by `GetComponent<Renderer>()`, that should be all.

Comment: It now says 'Unexpected token )' and 'expecting ), found "material" '.

Comment: WOOPS, this JavaScript, not C#, sorry. The JS syntax is `GetComponent(Renderer).material.color = Color.grey;`

Comment: I did that first but it said the dot was an unexpected item

Comment: hm, i tried it again and this time it's saying there should be a semi-colon at the end, even though there is. Here is the current code:                    'function OnMouseEnter()
{
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
}

function OnMouseExit()
{
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
}

Comment: Sorry, confused the language, see edited comment. Should be `function OnMouseEnter() { GetComponent(Renderer).material.color = Color.grey; } function OnMouseExit() { GetComponent(Renderer).material.color = Color.white; }`

Comment: Thank you Maximilian that seems to have removed the errors but I have assigned the script to the object and it isn't working in game.

Comment: I just tested it ingame and it works just fine. I created a cube with a Material attached (standard shader, red color), the standard box collider and the above javascript attached. Once I hover over the cube in the gameview, it becomes grey, when I leave again, it becomes white.

Comment: ah ok thank you, I'm sure it's something small. Question answered very well and thoroughly, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Since Unity 4.6 there is a new way of handling input events. One have to use interfaces from UnityEngine.EventSystems namespace. Look at this example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems; // dont forget this

public class SomeController :   MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{

    private bool hovered = false;

    // from IPointerEnterHandler
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        hovered = true;
    }

    // from IPointerExitHandler
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        hovered = false;
    }

    // from IPointerClickHandler
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // send some event
    }
}
```

Still, you have to add collider component to your object.